# jQuery load not working mobile browsers and Microsoft Edge

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

First I apologize for my bad English.

I load to my content bootstrap tabs via Ajax. But this code not working to Microsoft Edge browser and mobile browsers. What is the problem?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#streamTabs a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("data-url");
      var href = this.hash;
      var pane = $(this);

    // ajax load from data-url
    $(href).load(url,function(result){     
        pane.tab('show');
    });

  });

  // load first tab content
  $('#activity-stream').load($('#activity-stream').attr("data-url"),function(result){
    $('.active a').tab('show');
  });
});
```

Comment: What is the problem ? Well you tell us, 'this code is not working' is not a good description.

Comment: What is the value of data-url. First check the url provided by data-url realy a physical path in server. Also please clearly decribe your problem In wich platform you are working asp.net mvc or php?

Comment: i working php (laravel 5) but problem source another function. error fixed now and began to work. thanks